# Outlook mail addin caches cant reload the debugging version

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office365-apps, office365api

We are developing an [Outlook Mail Addin](https://store.office.com/appshome.aspx?productgroup=Outlook) for our product.

When i debug the solution in Visual Studio my Office365 Outlook account opens and i can see the plugin i developed in the list of outlook plugins and i can use it.

The problem is that even after stopping the solution in Visual Studio i can still use the plugin. And when i re-run the solution it displays the cached version of the addin not the current version that i have in visual studio.

Looks like the addin is cached somewhere. Can't seem to stop it.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is caching the files used by your add-in. If you deploy an updated version your browser will rely on the old files it still got cached. Deleting your browser's cache should solve the problem.

Comment: I started using an Incognito mode in browser it solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The add-in doesn't get cached, it always loads from the source location set in your manifest.  During testing, when you build the solution the app gets deployed to the Mailbox you specify.  However, the app can only run while your local web server is running.  The add-in's tab will continue to be displayed, but if your web server has stopped it will fail when it loads - it should never load a cached version.  You'll have to manually uninstall the add-in from the add-in page if you don't want it to run while you're not debugging.